# How to set default domain for a single IP address

Tags: nginx, server, debian, vps

I am running two .com domains from my Debian VPS NGINX server. The VPS has a single IP address.

I am trying to set the default domain - the one that comes up if I enter the server IP address in the URL bar.

I tried:

```
nano/etc/hosts
```

This contains:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
{VPS IP ADDRESS HERE}   debserver01.holdingdomain debserver01
```

debserver01 is my server hostname
*(I have hidden {VPS IP ADDRESS HERE} as this is for a private client)*

My NGINX server blocks in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ are as follows:

```
dotcomname01.com
dotcomname02.com
holdingdomain
```

holdingdomain contains:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        expires $expires;

        server_name {VPS IP ADDRESS HERE};

        root /var/www/holdingdomain/html;
        index index.html index.php;

        location / {
                index index.php index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                include fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME
                /var/www/holdingdomain/html$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

/var/www/holdingdomain/html has index.html in it

But in a browser when I enter {VPS IP ADDRESS HERE}, it goes to dotcomname01.com, and not  /var/www/holdingdomain/html/index.html.

Suggestions please. Thanks.

Comment: Test the configuration using `nginx -T`. Are the symlinks in place? Have you created another `default_server`? Is `nginx` restarting? Also check the error log.

Comment: thanks Richard Smith - I had forgotten to update the symlinks. It now works :)